# Filling in data frame column using regular expressions (?)

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

Ok, so I have a data frame of web forum comments. Each row has a cell containing an ID which is part of the link to that comment's parent comment. The rows contain the full permalink to the comment, of which the ID is the varying part.

I'd like to add a column that shows the user name attached to that parent comment. I'm assuming I'll need to use some regular expression function, which I find mystifying at this point.

In workflow terms, I need to find the row whose URL contains the parent comment ID, grab the user name from that row. Here's a toy example:

```
toy <- rbind(c("yes?", "john", "www.website.com/4908", "3214", NA), c("don't think so", "mary", "www.website.com/3958", "4908", NA))
toy <- as.data.frame(toy)
colnames(toy) <- c("comment", "user", "URL", "parent", "parent_user")

         comment user                  URL parent parent_user
1           yes? john www.website.com/4908   3214        <NA>
2 don't think so mary www.website.com/3958   4908        <NA>
```

which needs to become:

```
         comment user                  URL parent parent_user
1           yes? john www.website.com/4908   3214        <NA>
2 don't think so mary www.website.com/3958   4908        john
```

Some values in this column will be NA, since they're top level comments. So something like,

```
dataframe$parent_user <- dataframe['the row where parent
ID i is found in the URL column', 'the user name column in that row']
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vectorized option with `stri_extract` and `match`

```
library(stringi)
toy$parent_user <- toy$user[match(toy$parent,stri_extract(toy$URL, 
            regex=paste(toy$parent, collapse="|")))]
toy
#         comment user                  URL parent parent_user
#1           yes? john www.website.com/4908   3214        <NA>
#2 don't think so mary www.website.com/3958   4908        john
```

---

Or as @jazzurro mentioned, a faster option would be using `stri_extract` with `data.table` and `fmatch`

```
library(data.table)
library(fastmatch)
setDT(toy)[, parent_user := user[fmatch(parent, 
                  stri_extract_last_regex(str=URL, pattern = "\\d+"))]]
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be

```
with(toy, user[match(parent, sub("\\D+", "", URL))])
#[1] <NA> john
#Levels: john mary

nchar('with(toy, user[match(parent, sub("\\D+", "", URL))])')
#[1] 51

nchar('toy$user[match(toy$parent, basename(as.character(toy$URL)))]')
#[1] 60
```

Comment: In a similar line, I had `setDT(toy)[, parent_user := user[match(parent, stri_extract_last_regex(str = URL, pattern = "\\d+"))]]`.

Comment: This will fall over if you have a number in the domain name - e.g. `www.and1.com.au` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail If the parentID is 1 and the OP wants to extract that 1 from `and1`, the method you posted should also fail i.e. `basename("www.and1.com.au")
#[1] "www.and1.com.au"`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that they'd want to extract 1 from and1, just that D+ would get confused between the domain and the ID after the slash.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it is not clear whether the parent id occurs at the end or not.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, using the `basename` function from base R, which "*removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator (if any)*"

```
toy$user[match(toy$parent, basename(as.character(toy$URL)))]
#1] <NA> john
#Levels: john mary
```

Comment: `basename()` is a nice function in this case. I found something new from base R. Thanks. :)

Comment: @jazzurro - and don't forget its cousin - `?dirname` either :-)

Comment: Yes, I have checked that as well. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the prettiest way to do it, but an option:

```
toy$parent_user <- sapply(toy$parent, 
                          function(x){p <- toy[x == sub('[^0-9]*', '', toy$URL), 'user'];
                                      ifelse(length(p) > 0, as.character(p), NA)})

toy
#          comment user                  URL parent parent_user
# 1           yes? john www.website.com/4908   3214        <NA>
# 2 don't think so mary www.website.com/3958   4908        john
```

The second line is really just to deal with cases lacking matches.

Comment: Yeah, don't see a fully vectorized approach....`str_extract()` from `stringr` may look tiny bit cleaner, but not markedly. Good solution.

Comment: Ooh, combining akrun's approach and mine gives `toy[match(toy$parent, sub('[^0-9]*', '', toy$URL)), 'user']`, which is actually pretty nice, though I can only take partial credit for it.

Comment: @thelatemail Oh, I didn't think to use `basename` on URLs! I was looking for a function to parse the elements, but all I could find was `xml2::url_relative`.